# XPlane 11: How can I extract useful information about a flight given a byte string?

Tags: c, udp, xplane

right now my code reads and collects UDP packets from ethernet and stores them in a txt file. I want to extract certain values (ie. speed) from each packet but I'm seeing a lot of conflicting instructions on how to do this. Is there a certain x-plane specific package I can import? Any accurate instructions on which byte represents which piece of information?

Comment: Uh this is almost definitely hard to do since, x-plane is closed source. IIRC X-plane has a way of logging flight data, can't you use that?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already seen this, if not:

https://questions.x-plane.com/20760/where-can-i-get-x-plane-11-complete-udp-protocol

> Now, the protocol :
>
> The first 4 byte are the header. if xplane send data (stuff you
> selected in the data output) they read, in ASCII : "DATA". followed by
> 1 byte you can ignore followed by 4 byte, but only the first of the
> four is important : it's the index (the stuff in the 1st column)
> followed by 8*4 byte : they are the data. For more inforation also
> check "show in cockpit" in the preference so you'll now more about
> what the data are. then you have another pack of 4 + 8*4 until the end
> of the datagram. rince, repeat